# Angular + Laravel PHP Routing in .htaccess

Tags: php, angular, laravel, .htaccess, angular2-routing

There is a site in Angular and a server in PHP (Laravel).

The customer asked to remove # from the URL, after that, when updating the page, we catch 404.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The index.html and index.php files are in the same directory - / var / www / satu / public. 
Can I somehow solve this problem through the .htaccess file without changing the location of the files, or do I need to do something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot solve this through the .htacess file, because the URL fragment (everything from # on) doesn't get sent to the server